# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_head() i

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
        <a class="button_a" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/page-portfolio.php">ПОСМОТРЕТЬ Выигранные дела</a>
```

Когда переходит по ссылке выдает ошибку : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_head() .
А если перейти с панели управления ворд прес то работает в чем проблема?

Comment: Потому что это ссылка на отдельный php файл, а не на страницу. Это так работать не будет.

Comment: Что нужно сделать чтобы заработало? Не понимаю

Comment: пол дня потерял на это

Comment: Ну предположительно создать для этого страницу и вывести на нее ссылку используя соответствующую функцию?

Comment: Если Вы обратитесь к PHP файлу напрямую, он не отработает, WordPress не будет знать что Вы к нему обращаетесь, то есть не отработают хуки и не инициализируются соответствующие функции. Нельзя вот так просто напрямую обратиться к файлу темплейта, это не HTML шаблон.

Comment: Нужно это выкинуть вместе с файлом (в теме, мля!!!) и нормально создать страницу/запись. Т.е. через админку ВП.